# Konica Minolta BizHub C220 driver problem avoids us to switch to Ubuntu

Tags: printing

I am the guy who takes care of IT stuff in the company and I want to switch company to Ubuntu. However I could not make Konica Minolta BizHub C220 work with Ubuntu 32 bit 11.10.

It finds the printer in the network. I install with the local Ubuntu C360 driver (which should help) but when I send page to printer, it says it cannot connect.

I tried the Linux driver from Konica website, however i think it is already installed in the system.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As i am new to Ubuntu and Linux. after a little search i solved the problem. In the printer web site admin console there is a page about ipp protocol information like this:

Printer URI
http://192.168.0.103/ipp
http://KMBT6C980D.home/ipp
ipp://192.168.0.103/ipp 
ipp://KMBT6C980D.home/ipp

I just entered that info into printer utility. And now it works.